# Compiling failed

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, setup-di-compile

I am trying to compile Magento 2.3.1 and it says

> Fatal error: Interface
> 'Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\SearchResultApplierInterface'
> not found in
> /home/customer/www/xxxxx.com/public_html/vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Fulltext/Collection/SearchResultApplier.php
> on line 28

Could you please help me identify the issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you use: ElasticSuite 2.8.x for Magento < 2.3.5 Opensource:

```
composer require smile/elasticsuite ~2.8.0
```

see: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite

Comment: Great, Life savour